# Angular Frontend on azure isn't reloaded on mobile when a new main is pushed

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops

I'm using azure to push an angular website. The site will mainly be used on mobile. We're currently testing our beta version but when I update the website to a new version, the users' phone still opens the old version.

**Edit:** On my browser the same is happening, when i check sources I see that the index is updated with the correct main file, but the wrong main file is loaded (main.a8d2...). When I reload the correct main is loaded (here main.832a....)

[image: Wrong main file loaded]

In azure, on the app-service we've added an Application setting in the configuration called **WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE** with value **0**. We thought this would force the browser to not cache our site.

---

[image: application setting]

---

In our azure devops we made following changes in the release pipeline:

- Remove additional files at destination: **on**

---

[image: azure devops pipeline]

---

Which forces the app service to delete all the old mains it still has, ensuring there is only one main.js file, the current one from the update.

---

**Edit:**
For bundling i'm using what's in the box with angular, ref. https://angular.io/cli/build I've build using *ng build --prod* command, I've changed that now to *ng build --prod="true"*. It's during this install and build that a version is put behind my main file.

*My .yml file steps:*

```
- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
    npm install
    ng build --prod="true"
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
```

---

In my *angular.json* I have following configurations for my build:

```
"build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/PaySlip",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/web.config"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
```

In my webconfig I have:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
      <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/x-font-woff" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
     </staticContent>
        <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="redirect all requests" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" appendQueryString="true" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I expected when the users navigate to our website they'd get the latest version of our website. However they still end up on an old version. I have to manually clear their full cache and reload their page multiple times before it loads the latest version. Locally firefox does the same on my pc. It's only when i manually clear the cache of my firefox browser that the latest version is ensured to be used. How can I force the browser to use the latest version of my website?

Comment: Did you get a try with below solution? Any good new?

Comment: Was planning checking it out today!

Comment: One of the devs added the webconfig, I just noticed <clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" /> I put that in comment now and cleared the cache on the browser, this seems to have cleared the problem. I still have to verify with the mobile users, if that was my issue I'll post a solution

Comment: @JamesD how did you fixed this problem?

Comment: as mentioned in my own answer below, my web.config file was just configured wrong and I had to properly setup my auth callback page. These two issues were the root cause of my problem.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, has anyone found a solution for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72615183/how-do-i-clear-end-users-cache-for-angular-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't notice the caching element in the web.config file until later. Don't ask me who or how it got in there, I'd assume one of colleagues needed it for a specific test and forgot to remove it.

```
<clientCache cacheControlCustom="public" cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="365.00:00:00" />
```

After removing that line, I had to clear everybodies cache one final time manually, from then on everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned the latest version can be used if the browser cache is cleared. That means the latest version is successfully deployed to azure. The problem might be that your app doesnot have filenames versioning which cause to fail updating the cache.

Below are the possible ways to fix this:

1, You can use grunt-cache-breaker. It will append new hashes or timestamps to your app files as file versioning. Please check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-cache-breaker) for more usage about grunt-cache-breaker.

2, You can also use **Etag** HTTP response header which is an identifier for a specific version of a resource.
Please check [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-http-etag) for usage of Etag with angular.

Please check [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers) for more information about http cache control and etag header

Hope you find above helpful.

Comment: My main file is called: main.e27b1a28c098ea4f8e05.js ; which I thought is an indication of it being versioned... ?

Comment: Well if it's already being versioned without the above solution, I'm confused how another versioning system would help?

Comment: I'd assume you're then refering to try out https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers#cache-prevention?

Comment: @James D Disable cache might compromise your web performance. You can try out implementing etag header.

Comment: @James D Does the main file mark up changes every time when your app is rebuilt? Any versioning technique you already implemented.

Comment: Yes the main file marks up changes, and puts a new hash behind a newly build main file. The 'remove additional files at destination' in the pipeline removes the old file, as I thought that might've been my issue, but it doesn't seem like it is. Disabling cache will definetly compromise web performance, as the script has become long, that's why a cache clear for this site should only happen if a new main file is pushed

Comment: I've updated my question with reference to my yml, perhaps there I'm doing something wrong?