# How do I clear end user's cache for Angular 7

Tags: javascript, css, angular, cache-control

My problem is end-user browser cache issue in Angular 7.
I do not have such a problem in the local environment, but when I send the package in the azure environment, the end users do not receive the updated js, css packages.

I tried many methods, some problems are fixed when I do ctrl+F5, but sometimes it doesn't go away fixed  without clearing the browser cache.

Some changes I made and tried below,

> 1. I changed its settings for angular.json production as follows.

```json
"production": {
   "fileReplacements": [
       {
           "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
           "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
       }
   ],
   "scripts": [],
   "optimization": true,
   "outputHashing": "all",
   "sourceMap": false,
   "extractCss": true,
   "namedChunks": false,
   "aot": true,
   "extractLicenses": true,
   "vendorChunk": false,
   "buildOptimizer": true,
   "budgets": [
       {
           "type": "initial",
           "maximumWarning": "5mb",
           "maximumError": "10mb"
       }
   ]
}
```

> **2** I used the below command for angular package creation in azure devops
> `ng build --configuration production --output-hashing all`

[image]

Lastly, I added cache-control to the header field as below, but this creates a problem for json posts.

```
    headers.append('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
    headers.append('Pragma', 'no-cache');
```

What I want is to ensure that the end user receives the most recently created package when a new package is released.

> browser cache store

[image]

The config settings on the Azure side are as follows.

> web.config

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <clientCache cacheControlMode="DisableCache" cacheControlMaxAge="0.00:00:00" />
  </staticContent>
    <httpProtocol>
        <customHeaders>
            <add name="Cache-Control" value="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
            <add name="Pragma" value="no-cache" />
            <add name="Expires" value="-1" />
        </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>  
</system.webServer>
```

> index.html meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">

<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="0">
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache">
```

Comment: Where did you add this headers.append(...)? Is this an SPA client with .net core?

Comment: probably index.html ist cached from azure. The  cache-control must be setted server-side and not in Angular.

Comment: It would be helpful, if you can provide the script/pipeline command you run to deploy your angular app in azure. We had similar problem with AWS S3, so I might be able to provide you some suggest if I get to see the command you are running.

Comment: I second what @Zerotwelve said.  Make sure the index.html that is being served has the correct references to the new JS/CSS files, it may be that you're not correctly copying index.html.

Comment: I'm adding headers on the Angular cli side (http-client) use nuget package . @Bellash

Comment: Thank you for answer but Azure devOps side, the packages are completely deleted and a new one is sent instead.  Nothing about the old package is hosted on the server side.  Our problem is not Azure.  Azure change is applied, end user does not receive this change.

Comment: the server (azure) tells the client (browser) if the files should be cached or not.
Yes, the browser caches the files but it's the server that should send the headers that tells the browser to not cache `index.html`

Comment: @Zerotwelve - I changes index.html meta tag,   ```<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">```
 ```<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0">``` old version :  ```<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0">```.    Because the example below is basically meaningless because private, no-cache, max-age=0 and must-revalidate conflict with no-store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help. We solved the problem as below, the problem was occurring due to an incorrect meta tag setting in index.html.

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache">

<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0">
```

The old index.html meta tag is as follows. (wrong use meta tag attribute)

```
<meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0">
```

[http Cache-Control](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cache-Control)

n theory, if directives are conflicted, the most restrictive directive should be honored. So the example below is basically meaningless because private, no-cache, max-age=0 and must-revalidate conflict with no-store.

> **conflicted Cache-Control:**
> private, no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
>
> **equivalent to**
> Cache-Control: no-store

Answer (score 0):

In Statup class, aspnet.core I usually call an override method for the static files middleware like this

```
    var staticFileoptions = new StaticFileOptions
        {
            OnPrepareResponse = (context) =>
            {
                context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store");
                context.Context.Response.Headers["Pragma"] = "no-cache";
                context.Context.Response.Headers.Add("Expires", "-1");
            }
        };
        app.UseStaticFiles(staticFileoptions);
```

Comment: thank you for answer but ı use njsproj (note js ) Node.js and Express app. this client side app "startup.cs" doesn't exist here.